# What is the connection between energy in classical mechanics and thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics

In classical mechanics the concept of energy is very simple. If I have a bunch of particles $r_1$...$r_n$. Then the total energy is:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot r_1^2+...\dot r_n^2)+U(r_1...r_n)$$

Now in thermodynamics; I read from callen's book that Energy is a function that dependa on volume ($V$); number of particles ($N$) and entropy($S$). That is:

$$E=f(S;V;N)$$

What is the connection between these two Es? How can I go from $r_1..r_n;r_1'...r_n'$ to $S;V;N$. Given that the potential energy function is known (suppose lennard jones).

Main purpose of this post:

I want to find the connection between classical mechanics and thermodynamics; without discretizing the phase space and going through the concept of entropy.

Comment: Where did you get the first equation from? It looks like some form of kinetic energy in which case that would not be the total energy of a system.

Comment: U is the potential energy.

Comment: what is $r$ and where does the 1/2 come from. This doesn't look like any form of potential energy that I'm aware of. And even if it were potential energy, the total energy of a system is the sum of its kinetic and potential energy, both at the macroscopic and microscopic level.

Comment: Its a general form of the potential energy. 1/2 comes from 1/2mv^2 (the kinetic energy of the particles). r denotes the position of the particles.

Comment: The general form of potential energy has nothing to do with kinetic energy.

Comment: I want to know how you go from the total energy in classical mechanics to the total energy of thermodynamics.

Comment: U is the general form of potential energy. 1/2 mv^2 (v^2 is denoted as r'^2 in the above post) is the kinetic energy.

Comment: "I want to know how you go from the total energy in classical mechanics to the total energy of thermodynamics" Now THAT I can answer but the rest of your post just confuses things. If THAT is your question, I will submit an answer. Just let me know.

Comment: You are going to want to look into a little something called "statistical mechanics." See, for example, this website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_(mathematical_physics)#Ensemble_average

Comment: @BobD yes. That was my question. How you get from the variables of statistical mechanics to the variables of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Robin Wait. You said you wanted to get from total energy in classical mechanics, not statistical mechanics, to the total energy in thermodynamics. Which is it? Classical mechanics or statistical mechanics?

Comment: From classical mechanics to thermodynamics. See the two eqation above? I want to go from the first equation to thr second one.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question. It is only some of the comments above have created any confusion.